# make magit check uncommited changes when opening a file

Tags: magit

Sometimes I am interrupted while coding and forget to commit. I would like to be warned about this next time I open a file with uncommited changes.

I tried

```el
(defun my/magit-check-file-and-popup (file)
  "If the file is version controlled with git and has uncommitted
changes, open the magit status popup."
  (require 'magit-core)
  (when (and file (magit-anything-modified-p t file))
    (magit-status)))

(add-hook 'after-load-functions 'my/magit-check-file-and-popup)
```

which worked for a while, but after recent package updates it goes into recursive `require`, so I guess it is not the right approach. Using Emacs 25.2.2 if that matters, and latest `magit` from MELPA.

Comment: Maybe just use `(require 'magit)`?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help, but I managed to find a fix (I will edit the question now).

Comment: @TamasPapp Instead of answering your question within the description please write up your own answer and accept it after the grace period. That is important to mark the question as answered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that due to a recent change in `magit`, I now need to `(require 'magit-git`), not `'magit-core`. Also, `find-file-hook` avoids the recursion problem. The following works:

```el
(defun tkpapp/magit-check-file-and-popup ()
  "If the file is version controlled with git and has uncommitted
changes, open the magit status popup."
  (let ((file (buffer-file-name)))
    (when (and file (magit-anything-modified-p t file))
      (magit-status))))

(require 'magit)
(require 'magit-git)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'tkpapp/magit-check-file-and-popup)
```